# Change the position of text in HTML

Tags: html, css

Below is my HTML code that is working fine.
Just that I need to change the position of the texts here.
Basically, I have written a text like "Top Left" meaning this should be displayed Top left of the button and so on. Can anyone help me here?

```css
.new {
  color: black;
}

.act_button {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default action-button act_button" id="show" type="button">
  <div class="new">
    Top-left Top Right Bottom left Bottom right
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: [You can't add a div inside a button](https://caninclude.glitch.me/caninclude?child=div&parent=button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). This will be more robust when changing the dimensions of the button.

```css
.act_button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  place-content: space-between;
}

.act_button>span {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="act_button" type="button">
    <span>Top left</span>
    <span>Top right</span>
    <span>Bottom left</span>
    <span>Bottom right</span>
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: But if increase the size of the button, it gets shifted. Add my setting there, you can see

Comment: `place-content: space-between;` will take care of this. Alternatively, you could use `justify-self` and `align-self` on the individual `spans`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.
The texts are too big to fix in the button's dimensions but this can easily be fixed by changing the font-size or making the button bigger.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.act_button span {
  color: black;
  width: 10vh;
}
.act_button {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-default action-button act_button" id="show" type="button">
    <span>Top-left</span>
    <span>Top Right</span>
    <span>Bottom left</span>
    <span>Bottom right</span>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [You can't add a div inside a button](https://caninclude.glitch.me/caninclude?child=div&parent=button)

Comment: @Sfili_81 thank you for the comment, I did not know that. I checked and you can add a span so I changed div's to that.